# Ignore 3rd party Controller Actions in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web App that serves DevExpress Reports over a Web API interface.

I'd like to use swagger to be able to show consumers the usage and provide some helpful info about my Web API. 
However, Swagger crashes with the following error:

**NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.QueryBuilder.QueryBuilderController.Invoke (DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.v18.2). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0**

The problem is that Swagger tries to analyze the API contained in  DevExpress' **QueryBuilderController**. However, I don't want swagger to analyze these 3rd party controllers.
My question now is how to filter/disable 3rd party libraries in swagger?

Thanks
Sven

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got it working using a custom DocInclusionPredicate as [suggested here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1044).

Example code:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
      c.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
      {
          // Filter out 3rd party controllers
          var assemblyName = ((ControllerActionDescriptor)apiDesc.ActionDescriptor).ControllerTypeInfo.Assembly.GetName().Name;
          var currentAssemblyName = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
          return currentAssemblyName == assemblyName;
      });
      c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "FileService API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

Comment: After a lot of suggestions that would require code changes in libraries that i don't control, this showed up. This is a crucial answer that should be ranking higher in google!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swaggers `DocumentFilter` to achieve this, here is an example : [DocumentFilter usage example](http://fellow.aagaardrasmussen.dk/2016/10/06/exclude-episerver-web-apis-from-swagger/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it with some changes to get this working in .Net Core - but it doesn't work